# how to monitor number of connections in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I keep getting this exception under small load.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/127.0.0.1]
>   Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its
>   max size 256)))

is there an option to check number of open connections ?

Answer (score 3):

The driver provides a bunch of metrics providing you do not set `withoutMetrics` on the cluster builder. You can check the value attribute of the `cluster1-metrics:name=open-connections` mbean*.

Which version of Cassandra and the Java driver your running can make a big difference. With a recent version of C* and the Java driver it can have a lot more concurrent requests per connection than say a 2.0 version of the java driver.

You can use the `PoolingOptions` object to set the number of connections per host or the max queue size and pass it to your cluster builder.

Note that the domain `cluster1-metrics` is generated by `clusterName + "-metrics"` so if on the Cluster builder you set `withClusterName` it would change domain accordingly. It will also auto increment the `cluster1` to `cluster2` etc if you create multiple Cluster objects in your jvm.